# How to change the No Data message using iOS Charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

When using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/charts) and there is no data, there is a default message that says "No chart data available". Can this default be edited and handle translations?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can customize the chart appearance before data is shown.

```
@IBOutlet private weak var chart: LineChartView!

chart.noDataText = "Loading"
chart.noDataTextColor = .green
chart.noDataFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10.0)!
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI I am using a chart in a table view cell and found I needed to set the various noData parameters in awakeFromNib() for them to properly reflected.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    //show the activity indicator which automatically animates
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    
    projectionChartView.noDataText = "Loading..."
    projectionChartView.noDataFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .medium)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the default using `.noDataText` along the lines of the lines of the following:

```
lazy var lineChartView: LineChartView = {
    let chartView = LineChartView()
    chartView.noDataText = NSLocalizedString("chart_no_data", comment: "")

    ...
    
    return chartView
}()
```